# loop in a monte carlo simulation for a linear model in r

Tags: r, loops, montecarlo

so i need to figure out how to complete this task:
To get an impression how the estimators and tests work for this particular (finite sample) dataset, you shall perform a Monte Carlo study in advance. This means, you simulate 10000 times data from the model
yi =β0 +β1x1i +β2x2i +β3x3i +εi
with β0 = 150
i.i.d. 2 x1i ∼N(400,250) and β1=1
i.i.d. 2 x2i ∼N(5,6) and β2=4
i.i.d. x3i ∼ Bern(0.6) and β3 = −70 
εi ∼N(0,250)

(The last assumption ensures that OLS-estimation of (2) is valid, the inclusion of an intercept also allows us to use a standard F-test for later inference.)
    Then you do the following:
    a) Collect (preferably in a table) the bias, variance and MSE of all regression coeffi- cients.

so far i have:

```
lm(150+1*rnorm(50,400,250) + 4*rnorm(50,5,6) + (-70)*rbinom(50,1,0.6) 
~ rnorm(50,400,250) + rnorm(50,5,6) + rbinom(50,1,0.6))
```

but i'm stuck on how to get this linear model in to a loop so i can calculate the coefficients 10000 times.
does anyone has a clue on how to solve this or could at least give a small hint?
any help appreciated!!

Comment: well it is an assignment, but i am really desperate because the deadline is on Sunday. you have got a hint for me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, this question is off-topic and should be moved to: https://stats.stackexchange.com, since it does not address a specific programming question and instead focuses on the model, which is the business logic of your program. Please take some time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic